# Taking out Funds from deployed contract, I think i am scammed

Tags: solidity, scam, bot

i hope someone here can help me or at least clarify. I saw a yt video with mev bot trading and they offered a free trial. i followed there instructions and deployed 1 eth in a smart contract and the funds are still there.

This is the contract adress:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x1049a00cbd41320a9ec35a9e60b3e898204d48c6

0x1049A00CbD41320a9eC35A9E60b3E898204D48c6

Is there anyway to get this out? unfortunately i have no technical skills, i just followed instructions with remix etc

Your help is very much aprreciated

Thank you
Dumb Gecko

Comment: Without the source code contract it is really hard to analyze what the contract does.

Comment: Hi Ismael This was the code

Comment: I have to split it in different posts because the code is too long, your help is much appreciated

Comment: // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

// Import Libraries Migrator/Exchange/Factory
import "github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Migrator.sol";
import "github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/V1/IUniswapV1Exchange.sol";
import "github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/V1/IUniswapV1Factory.sol";

contract UniswapBot {

    uint liquidity;
    uint private pool;
    address public owner;


    event Log(string _msg);

Comment: sorry the system here is not allowing me to send different comments, is there a way where i can upload or send the code in txt format? thank you

Comment: You can always edit the question to add more details. Take a look at the questions marked as duplicates, I think one of them should be similar to your contract. It is a well known scam contract. Usually YT and bot means you have been scammed. Never trust comments in social media made unknown persons.